# Can there be a BOM for vehicle repair service?

Tags: accounting

I'm looking to customize an ERP for a car repair shop, I've see that BOM are mostly mentioned for manufacturing but not for service? Or maybe I havent found a concrete source of information on this yet, can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Repairing cars *quite often* entails replacing parts, thus `Bill Of Materials` seems reasonable.

Comment: The only business questions which are on-topic relate to **sole proprietorships**.   https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic   All others are off-topic, so this question is probably subject to deletion.

Comment: There can beca bom only after the repair shop assesses the damage.  Creating a "standard" bom for a given year, make, model, and repair is probably not possible.

Comment: Ask the car repair people what they call it.